# How do I show in the home page the facets shown in the product page?

Tags: commerce

I'm working on the http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart distribution.

You can see that the products pages shows the search facets: http://demo.commerceguys.com/ck/products

How do I do to show these facets in the First Sidebar of the front page?

If this can't be done, then I think theres a main part missing in this distribution.

Imho the facets search in the products page are great but users are very used to see a main navigation in the left side of the home page, like: http://www.amazon.com/ , http://store.apple.com/us

How can I get this feature? Maybe there is module for this?

I've found this one http://drupal.org/project/commerce_catalog but it seems to be the placeholder for a project...

Comment: Did you manage to solve the Facets issue @chefnelone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facets are built inside blocks. Just go to the `admin/structure/block` and search for *Facet API*, click `configure` on the Facet you would like to display on the front page, scroll to the end of the page and you will see a section *Visibility options > Pages* and on the right a selection named *Show this block under the following pages*.

You just have to add the pages where you want the selected Facet API block to appear. For instance if you type `collection/*`, the Facet will appear under every collection for the user to filter.

Comment: This does not work, I selected my facet api block to show only in the <front> page and it's not shown